# .dllファイルとは何ですか？ ソースコードをコンパイルした結果のファイルですか？　どういう形式で配布されるものですか？

Tags: dll

.dllファイルとは何ですか？
ソースコードをコンパイルした結果のファイルですか？
それとも、.dllファイル自体が何かの言語で書かれているのですか？

.dllファイルは、一般にはどういう形式で配布されるのですか？
・ソースコードとして配布される？
・それともexeファイルと一緒に配布される？

Comment: 質問内容が大まかで範囲が広すぎて簡潔で的確な答えは難しそうです。この辺の記事を読んでもっと範囲を絞った具体的な質問を考えてみてください。[ダイナミックリンクライブラリ - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA), [DLLとは](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library), [Dynamic-Link ライブラリ (ダイナミック リンク ライブラリ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-libraries)

Comment: > ソースコードをコンパイルした結果のファイルですか？  質問タグがwindowsになっていますが、OSについての話でしょうか？何か特定の言語についての話でしょうか？今何に困っていて質問されているのかが分かりません。質問の背景について説明いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: avformat-59.dllをダウンロードしたかったのですが、誰が開発してどこで配布されているファイルなのか分からなかったので質問しました。FFmpegをダウンロードすると同梱されているようですが、FFmpegの配布形式は多岐に渡っているためなかなか見つけられず、そもそも.dllファイルとは何でどういった形式で配布されているのか、疑問に思ったので質問しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) 固有の事情を言えば

ffmpeg は開発者からはソースコードのみ配布となっています。理由は「コーデックの使用料金を負担するのは誰？」というイヤンな問題を回避するためです。なのでネット上で検索すると ffmpeg の DLL を使う別ソフトの提供者の判断なり契約なりで「どれを使い、どれを使わない」を選択した結果の DLL ファイルがいろいろ入り乱れています。

@re9 氏が `avformat-59.dll` をあなたのソフトで使いたかったら ffmpeg のソースコードから `avformat-59.dll` を自分でビルドすればよいわけです。そしてあなたのソフトのインストーラに ffmpeg の DLL をインストールするよう追加すればよいことになります。ライセンス表示をどこかに追加する必要があるかもしれません。

当然ながらその際には各種コーデックのどれを使う使わないを選択し必要ならコーデックの権利者と契約して使用料金を払うことになります。 Windows に標準で付属しているコーデックなら Microsoft がコーデックの権利者と契約を結んで使用料金を払い済み（ Windows の購入価格の一部として末端ユーザが払い済み）だから、あなたのソフトがそのコーデックを使う場合には追加料金が必要ない、のかもしれません。その辺のライセンス問題は SO では扱わないというか扱えないというか扱っても誰も責任取れませんというか。

Comment: 回答内容難しかったのですが、そもそも「avformat-59.dll」は誰が開発しているのですか？ 「ffmpegに同梱されている.dll」＝ 「ffmpeg が開発しているDLL」ということですか？　「Windows オペレーティング システムでは、オペレーティング システムの機能の多くが DLL によって提供されています。」と書いてあった(https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library)ので、私はDLLは、どこかの技術系組織が開発して共通フォーマットを公開して配布＆一括管理しているのかと思っていました…(それをffmpeg が使用しているのかと思っていました)。

Comment: そのコメント内容はよい質問なので新規発言していただけると幸いです。

Comment: 新規質問投稿を行いました。

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic Link Library の頭文字から作った DLL と一般に呼ぶライブラリーの一種です。
もっと詳しいことは Google 先生に聞いて下さい。

.dll ファイルなのであればソースのわけがないと考えます(ライブラリー形式のファイルなのだから)。

「配布される」の一言で何がお聞ききになりたいのか私には判らなかったので、
それについては的確な答えが示せませんが、実行ファイル(.exe など)に固有のものならば、
実行ファイルと共に提供すべきものだと考えます。